# Clone draggable after dropping in targeted area with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I want some images to drop in a targeted area as many times as possible. But the image drops for only one time. My jQuery UI code:

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".draggable img").draggable({ 
        revert: "invalid",
        appendTo: "#droppable",
        helper: "clone" 
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
           $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
           var image = $(".ui-draggable");
           $( "<img />" ).image.src.appendTo( this );
        }
    });
});
```

Please see the demonstration here: [**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0n7r8823/2/)

From the example you see that the image drops in the div area **only the first time**. But I want the user to have the ability to drag and drop the same image *as many times as they want* in the targeted area.

So for example a user can drag and drop the image 5 times and there will be 5 images *cloned* in the targeted area. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. You need the `helper: "clone"` attribute indeed. The best way to do this is to create a new clone *when the drop event fires* using [**.clone()**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). Then just initialise it and you're done:

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable img").draggable({ 
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: "clone" 
    });   
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var newClone = $(ui.helper).clone();
            $(this).after(newClone);
        }
    });
});
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c9nyewfr/)

<sub>As a comment: I highly recommmend the method I described above as it is better to make the clone in the `drop` event of the `droppable` then to bind a `dragstop` event to the `draggable`. This because otherwise too many clones will be made: my code ensures that no redundant clones are produced. To see what I mean, open [**this jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o56hphgq/) (which uses the **wrong** method: *cloning on dragstop*) and try dropping the draggable *outside of* the designated area. What happens is that redundant clones will be added to the DOM. This is both inefficient and ugly and should be avoided.</sub>

Comment: that was a tremendous help. thnk you

Comment: Can you also look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221603/remove-cloned-image-after-adding-another-image-with-jquery-ui

Comment: @SaifullahAlam Of course: I've just submitted an answer.

Comment: Dragging an existing soccer ball also duplicates that object

Comment: @CarlK: Thank you for pointing that out. I've improved my code now.