# Remove cloned image after adding another image with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I have a nice solution from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218854/clone-draggable-after-dropping-in-targeted-area-with-jquery-ui/31219045#31219045) that successfully clones images after being dropped.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
var makeDraggable = function(element) {
    element.draggable({ 
        revert: "invalid",
        appendTo: "#droppable",
        helper: "clone" 
    });
}
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var newClone = $(ui.helper).clone();
        makeDraggable(newClone);
        $(this).after(newClone);
    }
});
// Initalise the program by making first draggable:
makeDraggable($(".draggable img"));
```

But the problem is **I want to show only one image at a time in the targeted area.** But currently all the dropped images are shown.

More specifically when user drops an image in the targeted area and later drags another image, the previous image should be removed from the dropped or targeted area and only the new image should be visible in the targeted area. See this demo: [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3pf6ays/13/)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply emptying the `droppable` target area like the other answers do, I would add a class to the dropped items and then remove them upon a `dragstart` event of a new `draggable`. Also, it's nice to add a little `fadeOut()` event when a new draggable is selected. However, as [Ishettyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572827/lshettyl) pointed out, one must also `fadeIn()` the element again if the user decides not to drop the draggable. This can be done using a custom `revert` function (see below).

The result is then something like this:

[image]

In my opinion this looks more elegant and doesn't confuse the user whether more items are allowed.

### **Code**

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable img").draggable({ 
        revert: function (socketObj) {
            if (!socketObj) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("droppedItems")) {
                    $(this).fadeOut(function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".droppedItems").fadeIn();
                    return true;   
                }
            }
        },
        helper: "clone",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(".droppedItems").fadeOut();
        }
    }); 
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(".droppedItems").remove();
            var newClone = $(ui.helper).clone();
            newClone.addClass("droppedItems");
            $(this).append(newClone);
        }
    });
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/czz0ofuz/)

Comment: Thats even more interesting @Jean-Paul

Comment: @SaifullahAlam: I've just improved the code a bit. Now it's perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

In the drop method instead of using .after use .append() like this

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
  var newClone = $(ui.helper).clone();
  makeDraggable(newClone);
  $(this).children(':not(span)').remove(); // <--- this will remove all the elements which are not a span before appending
  $(this).append(newClone);
}
```

Also, instead of writing drop inside div#droppable use a span like this

```
<div id="droppable">
  <span>drop</span>
</div>
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/e3pf6ays/14/**

Answer (score 1):

You were adding the clones one after the other with the below code.

```
$(this).after(newClone);
```

All you need to do is: empty the droppable container and then add the new clones, like below:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var newClone = $(ui.helper).clone();
    makeDraggable(newClone);
    $(this).empty().append(newClone);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3pf6ays/15/)

Comment: this solutions removes the words "drop" in the red box. Okay, just realized the OP is fine with it nevermind

Comment: @SaifullahAlam & Ishettyl: In my opinion it would be nicer to remove the items upon [**dragstart**](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start). I've shown this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221603/remove-cloned-image-after-adding-another-image-with-jquery-ui/31222109#31222109)

Comment: @Jean-Paul, absolutely, but what if the user decides not to drop that dragged image?

Comment: @Ishettyl: Ah of course, forgot about that. See my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221603/remove-cloned-image-after-adding-another-image-with-jquery-ui/31222109#31222109).